# Global variables in python between files

Tags: python, global-variables

I have read and attempted the answers here in stackoverflow but still cant seem to get this to work.  Im have a file global.py and a file weather.py. Global holds the variables for parsing a url and storing the global in that file like this:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYAPI/forecast/q/04002.json')
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
#location = parsed_json['location']['city']
day0 = parsed_json["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][0]
day1 = parsed_json["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][1]
day2 = parsed_json["forecast"]["simpleforecast"]["forecastday"][2]

dayname_0 = day0['date']['weekday_short']
high_0 = day0['high']['fahrenheit']
```

and here is my weather.py file

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication, QSplitter, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QColor
import Adafruit_DHT
import urllib2
import wunderground

temp = QLabel("Todays High: %s" % (high_0), self)
```

When i run the code i get the error that global name high_0 is not defined.  What am i doing wrong.  When i import the wunderground at the top does that not give me the globals from that file as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `global` file

```
from global import high_0
```

I would suggest you to rename this file though as `global` is a built-in keyword.

Comment: ok so i got rid of one error only to encounter this 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "wx.py", line 105, in <module>
        widget = MyWidget()
      File "wx.py", line 47, in __init__
        d = QLabel("Todays High: %s " % (high_0, self))
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Actually i just fixed that issue as well.  temp = QLabel("Todays High:{:1}".format(high_0),self) is the correct format.